# Variable value equals to 1 if it is utilized

Tags: python, optimization, binary, linear-programming, pyomo

I have an optimization problem which finds the minimum cost of sum of `capacity[] * weight[]`, written with pyomo.

[image: Schema]

`Mid` has an initial value of 0.03. `North` and `South` have initial values of 0.

`Mid`, `North`, and `South` have demand values of 0.01.

A constraint which allows initial values to move around between the nodes (`Mid`, `North`, and `South`), which is only restricted by the capacity of the line.

I chose the capacity variables as binary, so if a line(colorful lines in figure) is used, then the capacity of that line would be equal to 1. And it creates a cost in the objective function. If it is not used then the capacity value of that line is 0.

**Question:**
I would like to set the capacity variables as reals instead of binaries, and if they are utilized there should be a pyomo constraint which would then equalize their values to 1.

**Binary Case:**

```
# m.capacity->binary, m.flow->real
# m.flow is transfering the initial values depending on the not capped demand values.
# Lines are represented by the indices of these variables.
# If a flow variable has a value,
# then capacity value equalizes to 1 because of this constraint

def capacity_rule(m, sin, sout, tra):
    return m.flow[sin, sout, tra] <= m.capacity[sin, sout, tra]
```

**What I want to achieve is something like following:**

```
# m.capacity->real, m.flow->real

def capacity_rule(m, sin, sout, tra):
    return m.flow[sin, sout, tra] <= m.capacity[sin, sout, tra]

def some_rule(m, sin, sout, tra):
    if m.capacity has a value other than 0:
        return m.capacity[sin, sout, tra] == 1
    else:
        return m.capacity[sin, sout, tra] == 0
```

The problem is I can't really check if capacity has a value other than 0 because it is not calculated before the optimization is performed. Is there any way?

Main Idea is to implement **a constraint** which has the same effect of setting the capacity variable as binary in pyomo.

Here is the LP-File with 2 node system: https://justpaste.it/840wq

This would work, but then the linear problem becomes non-linear. Is there an alternative?:

```
def capacity_real_rule(m, sin, sout, tra):
    return m.capacity[sin, sout, tra] - m.capacity[sin, sout, tra]*m.capacity[sin, sout, tra] == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting this correctly, I would suggest turning this around:

```
 if use=0 then flow=0
 else flow is unrestricted
```

This can be modeled as:

```
 flow <= cap*use
```

where **cap** is just exogenous (constant), **use** is a binary variable and **flow** is a continuous variable (with bounds 0 and **cap**).

Comment: I tried to explain the question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4184983/converting-a-basic-milp-into-lp , the main problem is I want to get rid of binaries, while keeping the binary specialities. Therefore use is binary wont work for me :(

Comment: Great idea. If that works we would not need MIP solvers anymore.

Comment: Aight :) very well said! Just a question: what you think if I implement the constraint `x-x^2=0` instead of choosing x as binary, would it be more efficient to solve qp instead of mip?

Comment: That is a terrible idea, It is non-convex.